# Searching for a big amount of specific filenames inside a folder

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a folder containing a lot of files, i.e:

```
C:\Tmp\Input\random00001.txt
C:\Tmp\Input\random00002.txt
C:\Tmp\Input\random00003.txt
...
C:\Tmp\Input\random10000.txt
```

I have a big list (about two/three hundred) of specific filenames that I need to copy to another folder, i.e:

```
random00002.txt
random00009.txt
random04001.txt
...
random90000.txt
```

I've tried using the windows search separing the filenames using the `OR` keyword but there are too many files and it cuts the filter string...

[image: Screenshot of the windows search using the OR keyword]

I've also tried to write a function that allows copying files using a filter but it doesn't seems to work with the `OR` keyword

```
uses
  SysUtils, IOUtils;

procedure CopyFiles(const AInputPath : string; const AOutputPath : string; const AFilter : string = '*.*');
var
  Found : boolean;
  Res: TSearchRec;
begin
  Found := (FindFirst(AInputPath + AFilter, faAnyFile, Res) = 0);
  while(Found) do
  begin
    if((Res.Attr AND faDirectory = 0) AND (Res.Name <> '.') AND (Res.Name <> '..')) then
    begin
      TFile.Copy(AInputPath + Res.Name, AOutputPath + Res.Name);
    end;
    Found := (FindNext(Res) = 0);
  end;
  FindClose(Res);
end;
```

Comment: Do you really need this to be done in Delphi, or a shortcut through Notepad++ (or any text editor that support block selection) to generate a batch file will do?

Comment: Your code with FindFirst will work fine once you add the filtering on filename inside the loop.

Comment: Why don't you just use `TDirectory.GetFiles()` then check the files you want to copy?

Comment: A filter can also be `random06???.txt`. Also you don't need to iterate over all existing files if you know beforehand which files you want to copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of names to copy, it is enough to check whether current name belongs to this list

```
if((Res.Attr AND faDirectory = 0) AND (Res.Name <> '.') AND (Res.Name <> '..')) then
    begin
      if  Res.Name in Names then
        TFile.Copy(AInputPath + Res.Name, AOutputPath + Res.Name);
    end;
```

Implementation of `if  Res.Name in Names` depends on details - Names might be Dictionary, StringList, sorted one and so on ((you have not specified details )